Problem with flutter when trying to launch app after I upgraded
Since I updated my MAC to Sequoia, Flutter to 18, and my iOS SIM to 18, I can't run any apps.
I'm using VSCode. This is the error I get, please help!!!
Xcode build done.                                           13.0s
Failed to build an iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2024-11-07 10:10:15.855 xcodebuild[14993:140597]  DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion.
    2024-11-07 10:10:15.948 xcodebuild[14993:140578] [MT] DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion.
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
2
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:34B14090-28E7-45FC-97CF-0A5E28819376, OS:18.0, name:iPhone 16 Pro }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
2


what is your Xcode version ?
did you updated it , if yes are you sure it's stable not preview version ?

yes, Xcode 16.1

try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/78681786/1424762
